# What is the significance of the name Kumbhakarna?

Tags: ramayana, name, etymology, kumbhakarna

*Kumbhakarna* was the brother of Ravana. What is the meaning of this name? Is there any significance behind this name?

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumbhakarna) says it means pot-eared. By this logic, Karna was named after an ear. I find this difficult to digest.

Comment: Karna's original name is Vasusena. This name was given to him by his foster parents. Karna got his name after he gave his natural armour and ear rings. Till that time he was called Vasusena, Angaraj, Radheya.

Comment: @SreeCharan That sounds like a weird choice for a name :P Kumbhakarna had pot sized ears?

Comment: @SreeCharan thanks. Can you cite your sources since I wish to study further about it.

Comment: @VinayaŚiṣya You can read Mahabharata [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/) or read about etymological meanings of Karna [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karna). I suggest reading whole mahabharata.

Comment: That page says Karna means 'cutter/peeler of his own skin/natural armor'

Comment: @SreeCharan everybody knows Kumbhakarṇa is a character from the MahāBhārata. So it's obvious the source is likely to be from MahāBhārata. What I wanted to know exactly was, where are his names (Vāsusena Aṅgarāja etc.) given in such historical account since this is a huge book.